# windows.open, chrome.tabs.create, webbrowser.open does not open any browser/window

Tags: javascript

I have tried finding out why none of those codes will open my web browser or chrome and I just cannot find anything on it. What I am trying to do is somebody can search what they want and the script will open a few tabs based on the search query.

So I have tried all 3 but none of them opens my web browser, with the webbrowser.open script that I wrote, was copied from somebody else, it works for him but not for me, so I tried others and the other 2(chrome.tabs.create and windows.open) also do not open tabs or web browser for me

here is my code for the chrome.tabs.create and windows.open

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Product Review</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Search anything item you want!</h1>
<h5>Search the item you wanna buy with the price you are looking for</h5>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item"><br>
    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price"><br>
    <input type="text" name="tabs" placeholder="No. of Tabs"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="search">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
<?php
    $item=$_POST["item"];
    $price=$_POST["price"];
    $tabs=$_POST["tabs"];
    $submit=$_POST["submit"];
    if($submit){
        if(!$item || !$price || !$tabs){
            echo "Please fill in all the fields!";
        }
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var item = "<?php echo $item ?>";
    var price = "<?php echo $price ?>";
    var tabs = "<?php echo $tabs ?>";

    var thing = item + price;
    // for(i = tabs; i++){
    //     chrome.tabs.create({
    //         url: thing[i]
    //     });
    // }
    document.getElementByID('search').onclick = function(){
        window.open('http://google.com/search?q='+thing);
    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `getElementById` is capitalised incorrectly. The final `d` is lowercase.

Comment: Any error message in the javascript console of your browser? Does the html in your browser ("view source") look good? Also see [window.open docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: I should also point out that you are vulnerable to XSS. A malicious third party could submit a form to your site with a JavaScript payload. For an example of this, submit the form yourself with the item `"; alert("xss!"); //` -- if you want to inject a value from PHP into JavaScript, consider using `var item = <?php echo `[`json_encode`](https://php.net/json-encode)`($item); ?>;` instead.

Comment: Can you try to produce a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ? There's a lot of code here unrelated to opening tabs.

Comment: @John_C A snippet will not work since the search result is PHP

Comment: Also NEVER call anything "submit" in a form if you want to submit using script. Do you want to submit the form AND open a window?

Comment: Looking at the code, why are you even using PHP?

Comment: @mplungjan The question amounts to "How do I open a new tab". Most of the code here is not needed to reproduce that. If they reduced the problem down to it's simplest form (a simple script which calls windows.open) it would be much simpler to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @mplungjan yes I want the user to enter what they want to search for and then the script will search for that item

Comment: But why go via the server for a simple string concatenation???

Comment: @John_C So you want me to just type out windows.open("www.google.com") and then execute the script and see if it works?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ok will change that thks!

Comment: @HansKeﬆing no error message

Comment: @mplungjan how do you suggest I do it?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yup i know will do a simple regex later on when this thing actually works

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: Oh and um would the chrome extension of adblocker affect the tabs from opening?

Comment: And thanks guys so much for replying this is my first question no here thks so much for your guys help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is no jQuery in the form
- There is no PHP needed either.

Do you mean this?

It cannot be tested here because SO blocks popups

```
let tId = ""; let tabs = 0;
const urls = ["https://bing.com/search","https://google.com/search"]
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    const form = this.form;
    e.preventDefault();
    const item  = document.querySelector("[name=item]").value;
    const price = document.querySelector("[name=price]").value;
    tabs  = document.querySelector("[name=tabs]").value || 1;
    if (tabs >= urls.length) tabs = urls.length-1;
    console.log("tabs",tabs)
    if (item && price) {
      form.querySelector("[name=q]").value = item + " " + price;
      if (tabs >= 0) {
        tId = setInterval(function() { 
          form.action = urls[tabs]; 
          form.target = new Date().getTime()+1;
          console.log("action",form.action,"q",form.q.value)
          form.submit(); 
          tabs--; 
          if (tabs<0) clearInterval(tId);
        },1000);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item"><br>
<input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price"><br>
<input type="text" name="tabs" placeholder="Tabs"><br>

<form id="searchForm" action="" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type="submit" id="search" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: OMG it opened a new tab Where did I go wrong? and why does it need all the addeventlistener and stuff?

Comment: Oh why do I need jquery why cant i jus tuse simple js

Comment: There is no jQuery at all in my code - it is vanilla JS

Comment: And addEventListener is the RECOMMENDED way over onclick and onsubmit etc

Comment: sorry but how can you choose how many tabs to open, especially since the way to open the browser is through the html part

Comment: Yup it will open different links in different tabs on same item and price would .get('href') work?

Comment: What doe sth ehidden q do? is it a query?

Comment: Then why not just put ...gle.com?q= in the html form?

Comment: Because then you need window.open and that is what you were complaining did not work for you -

Comment: okok thks and um the new code opens multiple tabs now on the same search thks! not the links tho but thks so much for the help

Comment: Yup now it does not search for the item it just opens google but its fine I'll try to figure it out cause I'm also trying to learn thks anyways!!! :)

Comment: Um I just realized that there is an error when I inspect element that "assignment to const" to your older version of the script which includes the tabs and also the tabs wouldnt open more than 2 tabs. And when I submit the form again it will only open one tab. this is so frustrating

Comment: Sorry but I havent like set up the website yet and only have been testing it locally no my host using visual studio code

Comment: I have tried using for loops and do while which failed I tried windows.open again with them

Comment: I fixed some issues. https://plungjan.name/SO/multisearch.html -  the second+ window is blocked by my popup blocker :(

Comment: So for yours it opens more than 2 tabs? what was the problem why are u so good hahaha? and why even if its running on my host why is it that your pop up blocker will block my secondd+ tabs from popping up?

Comment: I had a spelling mistake and a loop that did not reset

Comment: Oh okok thks for ur help!